# Can I power the VTX and FC from the same vbat pad on the ESC?

Tags: wiring

I have the Hobbywing x-rotor 60A 4 in 1 ESC and the TBS Unify pro hv race.

Since neither my FC or ESC has a 10V regulator, I need to power both from the battery voltage. There is however only one battery pad on the ESC; will this be okay?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can.  Generally, you want to have your VTX and Camera on the same ground (in order to avoid video noise), so this approach will definitely work.  There is continuity on pretty much every VBAT pad, as well as ground, so having a single pad or multiple pads don't really matter much.
If you're seeing EMI noise effects, I would still highly recommend running a large capacitor directly on the pads of the ESC.

Comment: Thanks! There is a capacitor pre mounted, so it will probably be fine. I'll accept your answer as soon as I can.

Comment: Please explain the importance of insuring the VTX is rated for VBAT voltage.  Some VTXs cannot handle VBAT,

Answer (score 3):

According to documentation, the TBS Unify Pro HV Race can handle up to a 6S voltage (25.2V).  You didn't specify your FC, but as long as it can handle up to 6S also, then there is no problem running them both from the same pads since they could handle the same voltage.  It may be worth soldering in a capacitor to the same VBat pads to limit the potential for spikes to both your VTX and FC.